# Left transversal of finite group that is also right transversal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am working on proving the following fact:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup. Then there exists a complete set of left coset representatives for $G/ H$ which also form a complete set of right coset representatives for $H \backslash G$.

Here is the proof so far: Let $x\in G$. Then the double coset $HxH$ can be written as either a union of the left cosets $L=\{(hx)H: (h\in H)\}$ or as a union of the right cosets $R=\{H(xh):(h\in H)\}$. At this point I assume the following fact, which I'm struggling to prove:

> For $L$ and $R$ as above, $|L|=|R|$.

Under the assumption, letting $r=|L|=|R|$, we can number the cosets in $L$ and $R$ as $L=\{(h_ix)H\}_{i=1}^r$ and $R=\{H(xh_i')\}_{i=1}^r$. Notice that $h_ixh_i'\in (h_ix)H\cap H(xh_i')$ for each $i$, so that the set $\{h_ixh_i'\}_{i=1}^r$ is a complete set of representatives for all the left cosets in $L$ and all the right cosets in $R$.

Since double cosets partition $G$, we can repeat the process for all double cosets to form a complete set of representatives for all the left cosets and right cosets of $H$ simultaneously.

Any hints on proving $|L|=|R|$? I was thinking of using the orbit-stabilizer theorem, but was having some trouble getting it right. It could also be something easy that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: The usual proof of this uses the Hall Marriage Theorem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134523/left-and-right-transversals-of-groups/324509#324509

Comment: As to your specific question, the number of left and right cosets are equal, because they are both equal to the index of $H$ in $G$. (This follows from the usual proof of Lagrange's Theorem.) Basically, all the cosets have the same size, namely $|H|$, and the set of right (left) cosets partition the group, so there are $|G|/|H|$ of them.

Comment: An explicit bijection between the set of left cosets of $H$ and the set of right cosets of $H$ is given by $xH\longmapsto Hx^{-1}$.

Comment: @verret, in my question, $L$ and $R$ are only a subset of the left and right cosets of $H$. So my question is, why is there a bijection between $L$ and $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since distinct left cosets are disjoint and distinct right cosets are disjoint, and each coset has size $|H|$, then since $\bigcup L = HxH=\bigcup R$, we get $|L|= |HxH|/|H| = |R|$.