# Left and right coset representatives of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ action

Tags: matrices, group-theory, group-actions, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

Let 
\begin{align}
\Gamma=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})=\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}: a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}, \;ad-bc=1\bigg\},
\end{align}
the group of integer matrices with determinant $1$. Let $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Then through matrix multiplication, $\Gamma$ acts on the left and right of the set
\begin{align}
M_n=\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}: a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}, \; ad-bc=n\bigg\}.
\end{align} 
It can also be computed that the number of left orbits is finite (it is equal to $r:=$ the sum of divisors of $n$.) Further, the map
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a &b\\
c &d
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
d &-b\\
-c &a
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
(inverse map, then scaling by $n$) fixes $M_n$ and forms a bijection between the left cosets and right cosets. So there are the same number $r$ of left cosets and right cosets. I'd like to prove the following fact:

> There exists a complete set of left coset representatives $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^r$ that is also a complete set of right coset representatives.

Any ideas? I know that for any left and right coset representatives (respectively) $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^R$ and $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^r$, we have $M_n=\bigsqcup \alpha_i\Gamma =\bigsqcup \Gamma \beta_i  $.

Comment: Similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298084/left-transversal-of-finite-group-that-is-also-right-transversal).

Comment: Can you use Hall's theorem?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm having trouble applying Hall's theorem because $\Gamma$ is infinite.

Comment: @reuns it's true we can take $\alpha_i$ to be upper triangular, but are you saying we can take $\beta_i$ to be transposes of the $\alpha_i$?

Comment: a suggestion: Duncan Buell does this in book Binary Quadratic Forms for prime $n$ by giving an explicit set of representatives . Try that for $n=pq,$ for example.

Comment: @confused_wallet There may be a trick to reduce to the finite case, say taking a suitable quotient of $SL(2,\Bbb Z)$?

Comment: anything unclear ?

Comment: @reuns no, that really clears things up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$M_n = \bigcup_{ad=n, b \bmod d}SL_2(Z) \pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & d}, \qquad \qquad\scriptstyle\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & d}=\pmatrix{d & 0 \\ -b & a}\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}$$

Thus

$$M_n =\bigcup_{ad=n, b \bmod d} SL_2(Z)\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & d}=M_n^\top  = \bigcup_{ad=n, b \bmod d}  \pmatrix{d &0 \\ -b & a} SL_2(Z)\\= \bigcup_{ad=n, b \bmod d}  \pmatrix{d &0 \\ -b & a} \pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}SL_2(Z) = \bigcup_{ad=n,b \bmod d}\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & d}SL_2(Z) $$