# About left and right cosets of specific subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of the finite group $G$ Show that there exists a subset 
$ (z_1,..., z_r) $of $G$ which is simultaneously a set of representatives of the left and 
of the right cosets of $H$ in $G$, that is, G is a disjoint union of the $z_iH$ and also of 
the $Hz_i$.

Comment: This is a deep theorem of Philip Hall, the Marriage Theorem, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem

Comment: Thank you,I will read it.but Is there no easier proof for this special case?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/324509/43949