# Coset representatives when a subgroup $H$ is not normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

If $H$ is normal then the set of all left coset representatives is the same as the set of all right coset representatives.

If $H$ is not normal, does there exist a set of left coset representatives which happens to also be a right coset representatives?

Comment: Regardless of $H$ being normal or not, take $eH=He$, where $e$ is the identity.

Comment: Not the intended meaning of the question :p Anything aside $\{e\}$ though?

Comment: take something in the center of the group if the center is non-trivial.

Comment: perhaps this will help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178186/relation-between-left-and-right-coset-representatives-of-a-subgroup?rq=1

Comment: Thank you!  Qiaochu Yuan seems to hint at an answer in the comments.

Comment: I think Hall's Marriage Theorem tells you that the set of left cosets and the set of right cosets have a common transversal, a common set of distinct representatives. Indeed, I think it was in this context that Hall first came up with the theorem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134523/left-and-right-transversals-of-groups and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298084/left-transversal-of-finite-group-that-is-also-right-transversal and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268219/mutual-set-of-representatives-for-left-and-right-cosets-what-about-infinite-gro

Comment: Gerry, thank you for rephrasing the problem and the links. I had never heard of the notion of transversal. It basically a choice set. Thanks Anurag A. for the help!